# iterating over a list of values of single key in a collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, yahoo-finance

i have a collection of financial data stored in mongodb. each company symbol has its data. the question is how to iterate over the collection and change the value of the key which is the symbol company to print out the whole collection and this is my list of companies ['TSLA','TYO','C','LULU','DTV','SHS',' ZNGA']  and this is my cod which return the data of one company:

```
   from pymongo import MongoClient
   import csv
   host = "localhost"
   port = 27017
   databaseName = "finance000"
   collection_name = "income"
   client = MongoClient(host, port)
   database = client[databaseName]
   collection = database[collection_name]
   def finance_data(symbol):
        Earnings_BeforeInterestAndTaxes = symbol['statement'[0]EarningsBeforeInterestAndTaxes']['content']                                               
       Total_Revenue = symbol['statement'][0]['TotalRevenue']['content']
       return Earnings_BeforeInterestAndTaxes,Total_Revenue
i =collection.find({'symbol':'C'})

with open('D:/INCOMEdata.csv', "w") as output:
writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
for key  in i :
    print finance_data(key)

    writer.writerow(finance_data(key))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly. You want to retrieve the document/data for a given company. The company is denoted by a symbol example 'TYSLA'.

If that is what you need. Here is how you do it (assuming each symbol is unique)

```
company_data = collection.find({'symbol':'TYSLA'})
```

The above will return a dictionary. To access an element within the document you just use:

```
company_data['profit'] #profit is an example of an attribute name. You can use any attribute you like.
```

Assuming you have multiple companies with the same symbol. If you used the above command. you will get a cursor. to get each company just do a for loop example:

```
company_data = collection.find({'symbol':'TYSLA'})
```

Now to loop:

```
for one in company_date:
     print one['profit'] #python 2.7
```

Now to edit the say for example the profit attribute use **$set**

```
collection.update_one({'symbol':'TYSLA'},{'profit':100})
```

the above will change TYSLA's company profit to 100

**Update**

Assuming you have a collection with the symbol being any value of ['TSLA','TYO','C','LULU','DTV','SHS',' ZNGA']. to get the data for any of the symbols you use (assuming symbol contains any of the names (only one name)):

you use the **$or** as:

```
collection.find({"$or":[ {'symbol':'TSLA},{'symbol':'TYO},... ]},{}) #the ... are the rest of the names you need
```

The above returns the whole data for a given symbol. To return the specifics Total_Revenue and Earnings_BeforeInterestAndTaxes you use the following:

```
collection.find({"$or":[ {'symbol':'TSLA},{'symbol':'TYO},... ]},{'Total_Revenue ':1,'Earnings_BeforeInterestAndTaxes ':1, _id:0 }) #if you remove _id it will always be returned
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for reply. what i need is to iterate over the whole collection and retreive  all given companies data which are Total_Revenue  and Earnings_BeforeInterestAndTaxes . i have a single key which is the symble and multiple values which are the companies. i tried {symbol':['TSLA','TYO','C','LULU','DTV','SHS',' ZNGA']} but did not work

Comment: Oh ok, In this you will have to use $in I will update my answer

Comment: $in if you are using an array for symbol. I am assuming symbol has one name so use $or instead. Check my update

Comment: I got this error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Which part? when you where iterating you mean?

Comment: try instead of using a list use tuples. Assuming you are using list keys maybe?

Comment: after appling this i =collection.find({"$or":{[ {'symbol':'TSLA'},{'symbol':'MON'}]}})

Comment: Oh my mistake here is the correction:
collection.find({"$or":[ {'symbol':'TSLA'},{'symbol':'MON'}]})

Comment: Sure. Kindly mark the question answered if it answered your question. Thank you